# DeepDiff ignore with regex

Tags: python, regex, deep-diff

I have two objects:

```
d1 = [ { "id": 3, "name": "test", "components": [ { "id": 1, "name": "test" }, { "id": 2, "name": "test2" } ] } ]
d2 = [ { "id": 4, "name": "test", "components": [ { "id": 2, "name": "test" }, { "id": 3, "name": "test"2 } ] } ]
```

As you can see, everything stays the same, but the `id` property changes on both root object and also inside `components`.

I'm using `DeepDiff` to compare `d1` and `d2` and trying to ignore comparison of `id` objects. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this. I tried the following which didn't seem to work.

```
excluded_paths = "root[\d+\]['id']"
diff = DeepDiff(d1, d2, exclude_paths=excluded_paths)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `exclude_obj_callback`:

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

def exclude_obj_callback(obj, path):
    return True if "id" in path else False

d1 = [ { "id": 3, "name": "test", "components": [ { "id": 1, "name": "test" }, { "id": 2, "name": "test2" } ] } ]
d2 = [ { "id": 4, "name": "test", "components": [ { "id": 2, "name": "test" }, { "id": 3, "name": "test2" } ] } ]
print(DeepDiff(d1, d2, exclude_obj_callback=exclude_obj_callback))
```

What this does is returns a boolean for every deep component that includes the string "id" in it. You may want to be careful with this since you may exclude other objects that you didn't mean to. A way around this could be to set less generic key values for example "component_id".